# How to use double if statement using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a batch script with double if statement. I want to convert it to powershell. I tried this code but it still not working.

My batch script

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (
    IF NOT EXIST %FE_WKFD%\AUTO MKDIR %FE_WKFD%\AUTO
    IF NOT EXIST %FE_WKFD%\AUTO\POB MKDIR %FE_WKFD%\AUTO\POB
    IF NOT EXIST %FE_WKFD%\AUTO\file MKDIR %FE_WKFD%\AUTO\file
    IF NOT EXIST %FE_WKFD%\AUTO\Auto.txt ECHO Auto Text >> %FE_WKFD%\AUTO\Auto.txt
    GOTO B_F
)
GOTO Stop_F
```

MY Powershell Script

```
Function GUI_Choose
{
  & "C:\Users\run.cmd"
  Start-Sleep -s 1 
  $Log = Get-Content "C:\Users\log.txt" |
    Where-Object {$_.Contains("1")}
#####This part convert from batch file#####
  if($Log -and 
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_WKFD\AUTO")) -and
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_WKFD\AUTO\POB")) -and
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_WKFD\AUTO\file")) -and
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_WKFD\AUTO\Auto.txt"))
    {
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$WKFD_Path\AUTO"
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$WKFD_Path\AUTO\POB"
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$WKFD_Path\AUTO\file"
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$WKFD_Path\AUTO\Auto.txt"
     }
    B_F #Another Function
}
else
{
    Stop_F #Another Function
}
$FE_WKFD = "C:\Users\"
if(Test-Path -Path "$FE_WKFD\Auto. txt"){
    AUTO #Another FUnction
}
else
{
    GUI_Choose
}
```

Comment: What does `$log` output? a `1` or `null`?

Comment: The output $log is "1"

Comment: Are the variables `$FE_WKFD` and `$WKFD_Path` available in PowerShell? If they are environment variables you might want to use `$env:FE_WKFD` and `$env:WKFD_Path`.

Answer (score 2):

The original Powershell code contains a bug. Chaining conditions with `-and` like so,

```
(![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_WKFD\AUTO")) -and
(![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FE_WKFD\AUTO\POB")) -and
```

will mean that create all the directories only if all the directories are missing. In the batch, each dir is tested and created separately.

An idiomatic Powershell approach is to store dirs in a collection, iterate it and create what's missing. The edge case of testing for a file instead of a dir is not shoehorned in the same construct but has its own `if` statement.

A further readability improvement is to use simple conditions. Instead of `if something and something and so and so`, first test if `$Log` is set and then start testing for directories. Like so,

```
if($Log) {
    # A list of subdirectories 
    $autoDirs = @("AUTO", "AUTO\POB", "AUTO\file")
    # Iterate subdir list using foreach % operator
    $autoDirs | % {
        # See if subdir exists. $_ is picked from $autoDirs
        if(-not test-path $_) {
            # ... and create if doesn't
            new-item -itemtype directory -path $(join-path $WKFD_Path $_)
        }
    }
    # Create file if it doesn't exist
    if(-not test-path "$WKFD_Path\AUTO\Auto.txt") {
        new-item -itemtype file -path "$WKFD_Path\AUTO\Auto.txt" -value "Auto text"
    }
    B_F

} else {
    Stop_F
}
```